# How to send SMS anonymously?

Tags: service, sms, message, anonymous, short

Nowadays, I wonder how SMS services work and they allow us to send message without sharing any number. I want to know the logic of this process. For example, can I build my own SMS sending service? If you have any knowledge about this topic, can you share with me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio offers a platform to developers to do what you are thinking about. Here is the [SMS guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides?filter-product=sms). You can programmatically send text messages in the programming language of your choice. They also have a Rest API as well. I currently use Twilio as apart of a Electronic Medical Record Platform I built to remind patients about appointments.